# How to create a reusable Table of Contents Component in React

Tags: reactjs

I have the following:

```
        <TableofContents>
          <TocHeader>
            <span>Table of Contents</span>
            <hr />
          </TocHeader>
          <ol>
            <li><a href="#anchor1">Title1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#anchor2">Title2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#anchor3">Title3</a></li>
          </ol>
        </TableofContents>
```

I would like to turn this into a reusable component I can use throughout my React application.

What would be the right way to send and consume the dynamic content: `anchor title` and `anchor link`. And then have the number of list items be dynamic based on the number of list items provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export function ReusableTable(props) {
  const { tableTitle, tableRow } = props;

  return (
    <TableofContents>
      <TocHeader>
        <span>{tableTitle}</span>
        <hr />
      </TocHeader>
      <ol>
        {tableRow.map((row) => (
          <li>
            <a href={row.linkTo}>{row.title}</a>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ol>
    </TableofContents>
  );
}
```

You could do something like this, it's an example to make you understand, feel free to change the data structure.

And you could use it like this, where `tableTitle` is a string. And `tableRow` is an array of objects of the type
{
 linkTo: '#foo',
 title: 'Row 1'
}

So you could use it like this

```
<ReusableTable tableTitle="Foo" tableRow={[{linkTo: '#foo', title: 'Bar'}]}/>
```